# AgGridReact cells not rendering HTML from server side json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application that brings back an html formatted string.
When I show it - it displays the html tags.
I want to render the html. It should show some parts as bold, others as line breaks

Here is the code:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', '/admin/mvc/parsedrequests/get', true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ rowData: data });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
```

and

```
    render() {

        return (
            <div style={this.state.gridStyle} className="ag-theme-balham">
                <AgGridReact
                    onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                    ref={this.state.gridRef}
                    rowData={this.state.rowData}
                    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                    domLayout={'autoHeight'}
                    pagination={true}
                    paginationPageSize={30} />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

this is what I see on the page

```
"<strong>Email Type</strong>: NEW Request<br /><strong>Request Type</strong>: Request For Quote"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.

I modified the column definitions to pass in a delegate as cellRenderer

```
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    field: 'Meta', headerName: 'Parsed Requests', cellRenderer: this.htmlFormatter, wrapText: true, autoHeight: true
                },
                { field: 'Requirements', headerName: '', cellRenderer: this.htmlFormatter, wrapText: true, autoHeight: true },
                { field: 'Options', headerName: '', cellRenderer: this.htmlFormatter, wrapText: true, autoHeight: true },
                { field: 'Attachments', headerName: '', cellRenderer: this.htmlFormatter, wrapText: true, autoHeight: true },
            ],
```

And I defined the function/delegate as such:

```
    htmlFormatter(params) {
        return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: params.value }}></div>
    }
```

This formats the incoming value as html